# When calling Web API in ASP.NET Web form, it could not load file or assembly 'Autofac.Integration.Web' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, web-config, autofac, hangfire

Maybe this question is too broad but it has wasted a lot of time and I can't find out a solution for that. So I decided to share my problem for any idea.

I have a ASP.NET Web Form project that has a web page (.aspx) including one tag like this:

```
<iframe runat="server" src="API URL"></iframe>
```

By running the project I get following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac.Integration.Web' or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Autofac.Integration.Web' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

If I remove this tag, I don't have any error.

In fact, a couple of days before I added `Autofac` and it added following tags to my **web config**:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">      
  <add name="ContainerDisposal" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
  <add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>
```

When I am removing these `add tags`, I have no error. I don't know why these tags have negative impact on calling the API.

Another point, which it probably could be important, is API includes **Hangfire**. But as far as I know, there isn't any reference from Autofac in API.

**Edit**

The Web API is located in sub folder of Web form application in a operational server like this:

```
Web Form Application:
    > bin
    > web.config
    > Web API
        > bin
        > web.config
```

As you can see, Web form application web.config affects on Web API because of location of the Web API. Due to some reasons, I can't change the locations.

I have seen many topics and articles about it, but they didn't give me a clue.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message indicates that the assembly is missing in the bin folder. Does the `Autofac.Web.Integration.dll` file is present in your bin folder ? how did you add the reference to it ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Actually, yes the bin folder includes all of the dlls. My web form application just has `Autofac` reference. I checked before.

Comment: Do you have any nuget reference to autofac.web ?